# Why does it skip my command in C ? please check it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int inpa, med, oper, day, total;
  char agree;
  

  printf("                     Bach Mai Hospital");
  printf("\n\nHello, please enter your fee and we will calculate\npayment based on your insurance\n");
  printf("How many days have you been in the hospital ");
  scanf("%d", &day);
  printf("How much is your medicine fee ");
  scanf("%d", &med);

  printf("Have you undergone surgery (Yes or No)");
  scanf("%s", &agree);
  switch(agree){
  case 'Y':
    printf("Enter your surgery fee ");
    scanf(" %d", &oper);
    break;
  case 'N':
    oper = 0;
  break;
  };
  printf("%s", agree);

  inpa = day * 15000;
  printf("Your total fee\n");
  printf("Inpatient fee: %-10d x 15000 = %d\n", day, inpa);
  printf("Medicine fee: %-10d\n", med);
  printf("Surgery fee: %-10d\n", oper);
  total = inpa + med + oper;
  printf("\n\nYou pay: %d\n", total);

  return 0;

}
```

It skips my command from when I enter &oper

```
printf("Enter your surgery fee ");
    scanf(" %d", &oper);
```

And it is the result

```
  Bach Mai Hospital

Hello, please enter your fee and we will calculate
payment based on your insurance
How many days have you been in the hospital 8
How much is your medicine fee 90000000
Have you undergone surgery (Yes or No)Yes
Enter your surgery fee 80000000
PS D:\Desktop\Cprogram>
```

I would be so thankful if someone explain for me why

previously I have trouble with the "agree" variable which I declare a char but it understands "agree" as int. Thank you

Comment: If want `scanf()` to write into a `char`, or `printf()` to print a `char`, then the proper format-code to do that is `%c`, not `%s`.

Comment: Note that in C, a `char` is very similar to an int; the main difference is that a `char` typically contains 7 or 8 bits, whereas an `int` contains either 16 or 32 bits (both depending on the CPU's architecture).  The bits of a `char` are often interpreted as an ASCII code representing an alphanumeric character, but they don't have to be; `char` can also be used to represent a simple number.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s")` expects a null character(`\0`). Whenever you want to print a character, you should use `%c` rather than `%s`.So replace `printf("%s", agree);` with `print("%c",agree);`, then everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    printf("%s", agree);
```

This line seems to cause issue because:

- agree is a char variable in stack and hold only 1 byte
- When printf with %s, it is expected that you provide an `char` array end with value 0 which is string terminator.

Because of this when you call `printf("%s", agree);`, it will trigger a call to a string at address 'Y' or in hex value 0x59. And the access to this address is illegal and will cause undefined behavior for your program.